# how can you describe the sound of rustling leaves

Tags: onomatopoeia

how can you describe the sound of rustling leaves in just one word. If you want to write what they can hear as if it is onomatopoeia. I do not want to write that he can hear rustling, I just want to use one word

Comment: 'Rustling' is one word, unless I have forgotten how to count. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @Michael maybe you've forgotten and just guessed right?

Comment: Why would you need to write *he can hear rustling* in order to use the word *rustling*? Please provide a sentence that makes clear the specific context of the word's use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word *susurrus*:

> **susurrus** *n*
>   a soft murmuring or rustling sound; whisper.

It can refer to rustling, whispering, or a low, indistinct sound.

Comment: Sussuration is another word for that.